# Differences between $C_c^\infty[0,T]$ and $C_c^\infty(0,T)$

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, continuity, distribution-theory, weak-derivatives

I believe it is true that:

1. If $f \in C_c^\infty(0,T)$, then $f(T)=f(0)=0$.
2. $C_c^\infty(0,T) \subset C_c^\infty[0,T]$
3. $C^\infty(0,T) \subset C_c^\infty[0,T]$
4. If $f \in C_c^\infty[0,T]$, it doesn't necessarily mean that $f(T)=f(0)=0$.

Finally, what happen if I define weak derivative as
$$\int_0^T u\phi' = -\int_0^T u'\phi$$
for all $\phi \in C_c^\infty[0,T]$, instead of $C_c^\infty(0,T)$.

I will think more on this but maybe somebody has already studied it. Anyway, more information about these differences would be appreciated.

Comment: I think the most common definition of $C_c^\infty[0,T]$ is a function which can be expanded to a $C^\infty$ function on some neighbourhood of $[0,T]$. Then #2 is true and #3 is false (a function in $C^\infty(0,T)$ does not need to have any limits on the boundary). For the weak derivative, you will need to include boundary terms, or you will be in trouble. After all, the formula had better hold for the *ordinary* derivative …

Comment: $[0,\,T]$ is compact, so any function on that is automatically compactly supported, whence $C_c^\infty[0,\,T] = C^\infty[0,\,T]$. Your points 1,2, and 4 are correct, but 3 isn't; $C^\infty(0,\,T)$ contains functions that cannot be extended even continuously to $[0,\,T]$ (unbounded functions, for example). If you define the weak derivative that way for $C^\infty[0,\,T]$, then you drop boundary terms, and get, I think, overall a less useful theory.

Comment: Thanks for the comments @HaraldHanche-Olsen..

Comment: .. and @DanielFischer. I should write the closed interval in (3).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First let's assume some definitions (see for example [Gilbard-Trudinger](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=eoiGTf4cmhwC&source=gbs_book_other_versions) page 10): $C^\infty([0,T])$ is the space of all functions $f\in C^\infty((0,T))$ such that $f$ and all it's derivatives, can be continuously extended up to the boundary of $(0,1)$.

With this definition we have that all $f\in C^\infty([0,T])$ does have compact support, hence $$C^\infty([0,T])=C_c^\infty([0,T])$$

The last equality shows that $3$ is not true and $4$ is true.

On the other hand if $f\in C_c^\infty ((0,T))$, then you can find a $\delta >0$ (try to prove it), such that $f(x)=0$ for $x\in (0,\delta)\cup (T-\delta,T)$, hence $1$ and $2$ is true.

To conclude, note that if you define weak derivative (as you have formulated) by using the space $C^\infty([0,T])$ as a test space, then you have some problems with integration by parts (can you see this?).

Comment: Nice answer, too bad I used all my 40 votes today.

Comment: I am participating [The Crusade of Answers](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141/the-crusade-of-answers) if you are interested and got some time to spare. +1

Comment: If your displayed equation is true, why in Lions and Magenes do they write $\mathcal{D}([0,T];V)$ instead of just $C^\infty([0,T];V)$ (Banach space valued functions)?

Comment: @aere, What is $\mathcal{D}([0,T]:V)$?

Comment: @Tomás They define it as the "space of functions which are infinitely differentiable for $a \leq t \leq b$ with range in $X$ and of compact support. In Wloka (page 393), they define I think the same space as the restriction $\mathcal{D}((-\infty, \infty);\mathcal V)|_{[0,T]}$ (the restriction to $[0,T]$ of infinitely differentiable $\mathcal{V}$-valued functions with compact support..

Comment: If this is true then $\mathcal{D}([0,T];V)=C^\infty([0,T];V)$

Comment: Thank you, nice answer. Let me wait and decide which to accept as both answers are very good.

Answer (score 3):

I think the correct definition for $C_c^\infty[0,T]$ should be

$$
C_c^\infty[0,T]=\{ f\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}): \text{supp}(f) \subset [0,T]\},
$$

since this is the natural analog of the definition for $C_c^\infty(0,T)$. This gives raise to an equivalent definition

$$
C_c^\infty[0,T]=\{ f\in C^\infty[0,T] : f^{(n)}(0)=f^{(n)}(T)=0, \text{ for all } n \geq0\}.
$$

In this case 4 is clearly false and the definition of weak derivatives remains unchanged.

Edit: The first definition can be found, for example, in Trèves' "Topological vector spaces, distributions and kernels" on page 130 (where he gives the example of test functions as an LF space).

As I see you are interested in Lions-Magenes' definition of $\mathcal{D}[a,b]$, let me note that their definition is equivalent to $C^\infty[a,b]$ by Borel's lemma (I consider $V=\mathbb{R}$): They define

$$
\mathcal{D}[a,b]:= \{ f|_{[a,b]} : f\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}) \}.
$$
From this obviously $\mathcal{D}[a,b] \subset C^\infty[a,b]$ and for the other direction take a function $f\in C^\infty[a,b]$ and take $g\in C^\infty[b,\infty)$ so that $g^{(n)}(b)=f^{(n)}(b)$ for all $n$. This gives a function $C^\infty[a,\infty)$ which you can then "cut-off" to have compact support. Doing the same for $a$ we get that $f\in \mathcal{D}[a,b]$ so they are indeed the same.

Notice that they $\textbf{don't}$ define weak derivatives with respect to this space, but with respect to $\mathcal{D}]a,b[$ which is the usual space of test functions.

On the other hand this answers another question of yours on why is $\mathcal{D}[a,b]$ dense in $W(a,b)$: This assertion is the analog of the theorem that says $C^\infty(\bar{\Omega})$ is dense in $W^{1,2}(\Omega)$ when $\Omega$ has nice boundary.

Comment: Did you just come up with this definition or you get it in same place? My definition can be viewed, for example, in Gilbard-Trudinger book of PDE, ed.2001, page 10.

Comment: I can't understand why someone gives a upvote for an answer that does not have any justification. If in mathematics the phrase: "I think the ..." become usual, we would gonna end up with a lot of problems to solve.

Comment: @Tomás: I've edited to add a reference. Also I find your second comment unfair since your answer too lacks a reference to your assumed definition of $C_c^\infty[a,b]$ (Gilbarg-Trudinger only gives the definition for open sets).

Comment: He also gives the definition for compact sets too and it is the same as mine.

Comment: @Tomás: In page 10 of your link it gives: $\Omega$ a proper open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and then defines $C^k(\bar{\Omega})$ and $C_0^k(\Omega)$, here it doesn't speak at all about $C^k_0(\bar{\Omega})$ so I don't see where exactly you say it defines the space for compact sets.

Comment: Now I undertood what do you are saying. We are talking about two diferente things, I was talking about $C^\infty([0,T])$. Well, now it is a good question to ask to Op's: What is the definition that he is using?

Comment: @Tomás: Judging by OP's other questions I think this is a confusion of definitions: He wants to know if $\mathcal{D}[a,b]$ can be used as test functions, but the book he's citing doesn't do this. Moreover he took notation a bit far since, as I noted, $C_c^\infty[a,b]$ and $\mathcal{D}[a,b]$ are not the same, as opposed to the case of an open interval (which is where I believe the confusion started).

Comment: I see, well you have justified your answer and it is nice (+1).

Comment: @Jose27 Nice answer. Why do Lions-Magenes not write $C^\infty[0,T]$ then instead of $\mathcal{D}[0,T]$? Why bother with the compact support?

Comment: @michael_faber: My guess is that they didn't want to bother with the problem of extending a function in the interval to the whole domain. With their definition such extension is automatic.